# Chrome devtools extension to capture HAR

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Trying to make an extension to capture and store chrome HAR.

Intent: extension has a popup html page with start and stop buttons. Capture all network requests of the current tab between clicking of start and stop button.

Problem: since chrome.devtools.* are only available to devtools_page, how am I supposed to send event (clicking of buttons) from popup page to the devtools page.

Read that the background page is responsible for communication between several parts of the extension. Not able to understand how that can be used here.

Comment: Are you asking to get the HAR data of your extension? for the meantime, here's the Official Google Documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network, In terms of HAR, the `chrome.devtools.network.getHAR()` method returns entire HAR log, while `chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished` event provides HAR entry as an argument to the event callback.

Comment: I was asking about integrating this with a popup extension.                                     I found out that it's only possible when the devtools window is open.